# Javascript : Never returns from await

Tags: javascript, objective-c, promise, react-native-ios

I'm trying to use async/await, but there is no return from await.

This is the async function with await.

```
async _checkEmailDuplication() {
    try {
        console.log('Check Email Duplication is called');
        let res = await MyNetwork.checkEmail(this.state.email);
        console.log('Check email return value: ' + res);
        if (res === 0) {
            console.log('Available Email');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email Duplication Check Error');
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Check Email Call Error', e.message);
        return true;
    }
    console.log('What happened?');
    return true;
}
```

It is calling checkEmail function and here is the check Email function definition

```
export type EmailCheckResponse = { ret?: number };

class Network {
    constructor() {
        this._network = NativeModules.NetworkService;
    }
    checkEmail = (email: string): Promise<EmailCheckResponse> => {
        console.log('Network CheckEmail is called');
        return this._network.checkEmail(email);
    }
}
```

This is react-native module and trying to use Nativemodules from iOS.

And here is the Objective-C Native module exporting part.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkEmail:(NSString *)email 
    resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve 
    rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [GRPCCall useInsecureConnectionsForHost:kHostAddress];

        AccountService *client = [[AccountService alloc] initWithHost:kHostAddress];

        EmailCheckRequest *request = [EmailCheckRequest message];
        request.email = email;
        NSLog(@"Requested Email: %@\n", request.email);

        [client checkEmailWithRequest:request handler:^(EmailCheckResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Email Check result: %d\n", response.ret);
        }];
    }
}
```

The problem is that after calling checkEmail, it got stuck. No return.

The log says

2017-07-16 16:01:29.355 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Check Email Duplication is called
2017-07-16 16:01:29.356 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Network CheckEmail is called
2017-07-16 16:01:29.364 [50446:3725293] Requested Email: xxx@xxx.com
2017-07-16 16:01:29.384 [50446:3725170] Email Check result: 0

It seems that Objective-C module was called successfully, but no coming back from it. After calling await checkEmail, nothing happens.

Is there anyone who can tell what is wrong with my codes? =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see from your React native module implementation, your forgot to call `resolve` and `reject` methods which are crucial to work promises the way they have promised to work.

```
[client checkEmailWithRequest:request handler:^(EmailCheckResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Email Check result: %d\n", response.ret);
        if(response){
           resolve(response);
       }else{
           reject(@"no_events", @"There were no events", error);
       }
 }
];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Awesome! I have no Objective-C background knowledge and that part was another point that I was wondering.

One thing to add. reject(RCTPromiseRejectBlock) now takes 3 arguments.

Comment: Updated the answer. If it solved your problem, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: Just did it. I was not used to the overall flow and UI and just found the "answer" button. Anyway, thanks for your answer!!

Comment: By the way, even though I added resolve/reject methods, the return value of the checkEmail function is null. Do you know why it is?
When I checked the response.ret value at Objective-C, there was a valid return value and it was handed over to resolve method, but after calling checkEmail method at Javascript, the return value is null.
"Check email return value: null"

Comment: let me know the log sequence . is 'Check email return value: null' log is occuring before or after the  'Email Check result: %d\n' native log ?

Comment: After the Email Check result %d

2017-07-17 00:22:18.928 [info] [tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Check Email Duplication is called
2017-07-17 00:22:18.934 [64873:5050543] Requested Email: xxx@xxx.com
2017-07-17 00:22:18.954 [64873:5049975] Email Check result: 2
2017-07-17 00:22:18.956 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Check email return value: null
2017-07-17 00:22:18.956 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Email Duplication Check Error

Is there any missing part?

Comment: not sure may be the way your handling Promise in check email is causing the problem,try some thing like this. `checkEmail = (email: string)=>{
 return new Promise<any>( (resolve,reject) => {
        console.log('Network CheckEmail is called');
        this._network.checkEmail( email ).then( ( res ) => resolve( res )) } );
}`

Comment: also try some thing like this. `checkEmail =async (email: string)  => {
        console.log('Network CheckEmail is called');
        res = await this._network.checkEmail( email );
        return res
}`

Comment: I am new to Typescript, If there is any syntax issues kindly correct before u try. Let me know the results.

Comment: I did both, but still the same. returns null. Would it be Javascript side problem? or Objective-C side problem?

Comment: Hi @yaswanthsvist, I thought it would be better to open a new thread to discuss it, rather than comment and here is the link. Hope your feedback. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148675/exportingbridging-method-from-objective-c-to-react-native-with-promise-retur