# Exporting(bridging) method from Objective-C to React native with Promise : returns null only

Tags: objective-c, react-native, promise, export, bridge

I'm trying to export objective-c methods to react-native with Promise, but when I check the return value at react-native, it's always null, even though objective-c returns a correct data.

Here is my objective-c method.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkEmail:(NSString *)email 
    resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve 
    rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [GRPCCall useInsecureConnectionsForHost:kHostAddress];

        AccountService *client = [[AccountService alloc] initWithHost:kHostAddress];

        EmailCheckRequest *request = [EmailCheckRequest message];
        request.email = email;
        NSLog(@"Requested Email: %@\n", request.email);

        [client checkEmailWithRequest:request handler:^(EmailCheckResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Email Check result: %d\n", response.ret);
            if (response) {
                NSLog(@"Resolved response\n");
                resolve(response);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Rejected response\n");
                reject(@"no_events", @"There was no event", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

And the react-native side method definition is like this.

```
checkEmail = (email:string) => {
    console.log('Network Check Email is called');
    return this._network.checkEmail(email);
}
```

or

```
checkEmail = (email:string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Network Check Email is called');
        this._network.checkEmail(email).then((res) => {
            console.log('check email result: ' + res);
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

I tested both cases, but the return value of checkEmail is always **Null**.

```
async _checkEmailDuplication() {
    try {
        console.log('Check Email Duplication is called');
        const res = await MyNetwork.checkEmail(this.state.email);
        console.log('Check email return value: ' + res);
        if (res === 0) {
            console.log('Available Email');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Email Duplication Check Error');
            this.state.errMsg = WSStrings.errCodes[res];
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error('Check Email Call Error', e.message);
        this.state.errMsg = e.message;
        return true;
    }
}
```

The below is the log from Xcode, when I run the above code.

```
2017-07-18 00:51:43.781 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Check Email Duplication is called
2017-07-18 00:51:43.782 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Network Check Email is called
2017-07-18 00:51:43.839 [5782:110747] Requested Email: xxx@xxx.com
2017-07-18 00:51:43.872 [5782:109339] Email Check result: 2
2017-07-18 00:51:43.872 [5782:109339] Resolved response
2017-07-18 00:51:43.873 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] check email result: null
2017-07-18 00:51:43.874 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Check email return value: null
2017-07-18 00:51:43.874 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Email Duplication Check Error
```

It does not get the correct return code, but just **NULL** and can't go to the next step.

Is there any grammatical error at Objective-C code or react-native code?

I have no Objective-C background knowledge and I don't have enough experience in Promise and bridge of react-native, so if someone can help me, that will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.
`resolve(response)` This part was the problem.

The response object was not interpreted by Javascript side, so had to hand over NSDictionary object like this, instead of handing over response object itself.

```
            if (response) {
                NSLog(@"User ID: %d Language: %@\n", response.uid, response.language);
                NSDictionary *dictRes = @{
                    @"ret":@(response.ret),
                    @"uid":@(response.uid),
                    @"lang":response.language
                    };
                resolve(dictRes);
            }
```

Anyway, it was Objective-C side issue, not Javascript.

Problem solved!!